# MySQL view with comma separated result

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

**I am creating a view in MySQL Workbench:**

**Tables:**

[image]

I want to create a view that will return records in such a way where, i get all rows from **addressBook** table & **data field** values separated by comma from **addressBookData** table.

**How to do that?**

**My view is like this:**

```
CREATE VIEW `addressBook_view` AS
SELECT
    `addressBook`.*,
    (SELECT `addressBookData`.`data` FROM `addressBookData` WHERE `addressBook_id` = `id` AND `type` = 'mobile') AS `mobile`,
    (SELECT `addressBookData`.`data` FROM `addressBookData` WHERE `addressBook_id` = `id` AND `type` = 'phone') AS `phone`,
    (SELECT `addressBookData`.`data` FROM `addressBookData` WHERE `addressBook_id` = `id` AND `type` = 'fax') AS `fax`
FROM
    `addressBook`
```

Comment: Why do you want a *view*?

Comment: I'm creating MySQL View, because i don't want to run multiple queries in PHP

Comment: Sorry. The logic of that statement escapes me.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT ab.*, abd.type, GROUP_CONCAT(abd.data SEPARATOR ',')
FROM addressBook ab 
LEFT JOIN addressBookData abd ON ab.id = abd.addressBook_id
GROUP BY ab.id, abd.type
```

You can create view based on this query by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for GROUP_CONCAT

Answer (score 0):

**Ended up doing this:**

```
CREATE VIEW `addressBook_view` AS
SELECT
    `addressBook`.*
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`data`) FROM `addressBookData` WHERE `addressBook_id` = `addressBook`.`id` AND `type` = 'mobile' GROUP BY `id`) AS `mobile`,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`data`) FROM `addressBookData` WHERE `addressBook_id` = `addressBook`.`id` AND `type` = 'phone' GROUP BY `id`) AS `phone`,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`data`) FROM `addressBookData` WHERE `addressBook_id` = `addressBook`.`id` AND `type` = 'fax' GROUP BY `id`) AS `fax`
FROM
    `addressBook`
```